# jq - How to print key (not value of key) and iterate over keys to print sub value

Tags: jq

I can print the keys:

```
$ jq -r '.indices | keys[]'
plan
resource
user
```

I can print the sub value:

```
$ jq '.indices[] | .primaries.docs.count'
14208
1427143
104475
```

How do I print the key and subvalue?

```
plan: 14208
resource: 1427143
user: 104475
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following might work:

```
$ jq -r '.indices | to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value.primaries.docs.count)"' input.json
plan: 14208
resource: 1427143
user: 104475
```

The above assumes the input is:

```
{
  "indices": {
    "plan":     { "primaries": { "docs": { "count": 123 }}},
    "resource": { "primaries": { "docs": { "count": 456 }}},
    "user":     { "primaries": { "docs": { "count": 789 }}}
  }
}
```

`to_entries` will convert the object `indices` to an array:

```
[
  { "key": "plan", "value": { ... } },
  ...,
  ...
]
```

Which can then be easily mapped.

Comment: Thank you @andlrc. This helped me understand `to_entries` better.

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer No problem, I'm happy that it worked. You should consider to post relevant input in the future as it makes it easier to provide a valid answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that uses keys directly:

```
  .indices
| keys[] as $k
| "\($k): \(.[$k].primaries.docs.count)"
```