# how to print all key and one of the values from json using jq

Tags: jq

I have a test.json file and I want to print:

```
prob1, 9
prob2, 10
prob3, 11

cat test.json | jq --raw-output '.[].abc'
```

return 9,10,11 but I am not sure how to print keys as well.

```
{
   "prob1":{
      "abc":9,
      "abcd":2,
      "Foo":3
   },
   "prob2":{
      "abc":10,
      "abcd":2,
      "Foo":3
   },
   "prob3":{
      "abc":11,
      "abcd":2,
      "Foo":3
   }
}
```

Comment: found a related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386019/jq-how-to-print-key-not-value-of-key-and-iterate-over-keys-to-print-sub-valu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\( .key ): \( .value.abc )"'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lU7XzQRbACV) on jqplay

```bash
jq -r 'keys[] as $key | .[$key] | "\( $key ): \( .abc )"'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uD_3o6KQbG3) on jqplay

Answer (score 1):

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value.abc)"'
```

```
prob1: 9
prob2: 10
prob3: 11
```